# Vim map a key combination while in insert mode

Tags: vim

This is probably an easy question for most vim users.

I want to `map :tabn` to `<C-Tab>`. It works perfectly while I'm in normal mode but when I'm in my insert mode (typing code) it just inserts tabs characters.

In my vimrc file I have

```
map <C-Tab> :tabn<CR>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
:imap <C-Tab> <Esc>:tabn<CR>
```

That will leave you in normal mode after switching to the next tab. You could instead use this:

```
:imap <C-Tab> <C-O>:tabn<CR>
```

which will put you back into insert mode in the next tab at the position where you left the cursor in that tab.

Comment: Is there any way to let it stay in insert mode or go back in insert mode?

Comment: @Til: The `<C-O>` should interrupt insert mode for the duration of the command, then return to insert mode. Another way to go back to insert mode is to use `:startinsert`. See `:help i_CTRL-O` and `:help :startinsert`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `imap` command. You will also need to prepend `<ESC>` to it to make it leave insert mode first.

```
imap <C-Tab> <ESC>:tabn<CR>
```

Comment: When I did that it just inserted :tabn into my document. In normal mode it still worked as expected

Comment: Edited accordingly, @coderdave.